# Pyforms, pysettings and pyinstaller, object has no attribute 'settings'

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, pyforms

I have problem with pyforms and pysettings in python 2.7 after compilation to the executable file.

Script runs normally and without errors when executed by "python godziny.py".

However after I create executable file (currently I use pyinstaller, but I also tried py2exe and cx_freeze with the same problem) I start the app and receive following:
`C:\...>dist\godziny\godziny.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "godziny.py", line 10, in <module>
        from   pyforms          import BaseWidget
    File "c:\users\...\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-hzzm3w\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    File "site-packages\pyforms\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    File "site-packages\pysettings\settings_manager.py", line 22, in __add__
    File "site-packages\pysettings\settings_manager.py", line 16, in __load_module
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'settings'
Failed to execute script godziny`

I'm using Python 2.7, with pysettings from [Pysettings](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pysettings/tree/92bde8c680bc0a00ae97cc09bd4dab1b697d6ed2) and pyforms from pip (0.1.7.3). Pyinstaller doesn't report any errors during compilation.